# file handling I/O reading file

Tags: python, file, search, operator-keyword

i will be grateful to have some help.(the record in the text file: brazil\n12\nethopia\n23\nmada\n10\n). for example when i type  "brazil" OR part of the beginning like (b or br or bra and so on) the output is:
brazil
12
i want the output to be correct ONLY when the full name is written NOT the beginning part of it. i tried ==  in the place of in (.... if search in line:....) but it does not work. so thanks in advance for your help

```
def main():

    def data():
        dfile= open("coffeedata.txt","a")
        user = input('Insert a record: ')
        while user == "y":
            desr = input("name of coffe: ")
            dfile.write(desr+"\n")
            qty = float(input("insert the quantity: "))
            dfile.write(str(qty)+"\n")
            user = input('do you have new record: y or n: ')
        else:
            print("no data entry")
    data()


    def dreading():
        with open("coffeedata.txt","r") as dfile:
            for line in dfile:
                print (line.rstrip("\n"))
    dreading()

    def searching():
        found= False
        search = input("name of coffee:")  
        with open("coffeedata.txt", "r") as dfile:
            print(dfile)
            for line in dfile:
                if search in line:  
                    print(line.rstrip("\n"))
                    print(type(line))
                    qty=float(dfile.readline())
                    print(qty)
                    print(type(qty))
                    found=True
            if not found:
                print("the coffee is not in the record")

    searching()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate *search* with *'\n* in your case

```
if search + "\n" in line:
```

>

```
def main():
  def data():
      dfile= open("coffeedata.txt","a")
      user = input('Insert a record: ')
      while user == "y":
          desr = input("name of coffe: ")
          dfile.write(desr+"\n")
          qty = float(input("insert the quantity: "))
          dfile.write(str(qty)+"\n")
          user = input('do you have new record: y or n: ')
      else:
          print("no data entry")
  data()


  def dreading():
      with open("coffeedata.txt","r") as dfile:
          for line in dfile:
              print (line.rstrip("\n"))
  dreading()

  def searching():
      found= False
      search = input("name of coffee:")  
      with open("coffeedata.txt", "r") as dfile:
          print(dfile)
          for line in dfile:
              if search + "\n" in line:  
                  print(line.rstrip("\n"))
                  print(type(line))
                  qty=float(dfile.readline())
                  print(qty)
                  print(type(qty))
                  found=True
          if not found:
              print("the coffee is not in the record")

  searching()

main()
```

Comment: THANKS YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: You welcome. You can accept my answer if is what you need

Comment: hello P47 R1ck, how can I modify the quantity in a cleanness way. for example change the figure 12 after brazil to another one.